# sizeof operator returning different sizes

Tags: c++

The `sizeof` operator in C++ is giving me a different size inside a function and different in the main. Any idea why?

```
void createPacket(char packet[]){
    int size = sizeof(packet);
    printf("%d\n", size);
}

int main(){
    char packet[PKTSIZE];
    createPacket(packet);
    int size = sizeof(packet);
    printf("%d\n", size);
}
```

I was expecting

```
9
9
```

but I get

```
8
9
```

Any idea why?

Comment: That's because `char packet[]` decays to a pointer, so you're taking the size of a pointer.

Comment: You can write `sizeof packet`. Parentheses are for type like `sizeof (int)`.

Answer (score 0):

If PKTSIZE is 9 and if you compiled it on a x64 platform than you get in main the array size and in the function the pointer size.

Comment: can I check the array size inside?

Comment: @user2589783, Use `std::array`.

Comment: I find the first two ifs misleading. The fact that you get the array size in `main` and the pointer size in the function are not dependent on either of those.

Comment: where should i use std::array?

Comment: @user2589783, In place of regular ones, unless it's a character array meant as a string, in which case `std::string` is a better option (you could argue its value for *any* character array), or a dynamic array, in which case `std::vector` is better. `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` can be useful sometimes, but not nearly as often from what I've found, and especially not once C++14 comes with its two new features relating to arrays.

Comment: You should note that sizeof is calculated on compile time. So far it won't give you that results you are expecting.